# Calling a function in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Looked around everywhere for this with no real luck.

I'm looking to call a function into another function using google apps scripts. Both functions are in the current project yet when I do, the function I am calling is not being pulled through as variables are not linking between the two functions

The function I wish to call is called ' `getDates` ' which has the variable ' `year` ' in it. However when I call the function then the script goes to call ' `year` ' it is returning undefined.

This is the `getDates` Function:

```
  function getDates {
 var startDate = new Date(sheet.getRange("B1").getValue());
var year = startDate.getFullYear();}
```

And I am looking to call this function into the following:

```
    function one {

         getDates();

          var url = "https://(hidden url)" + year; 

        UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
        var dataAll = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()); //
  var dataSet = dataAll;

  var rows = [],
      data;


  for (i = 0; i < Object.keys(dataSet).length; i++) { data = dataSet[Object.keys(dataSet)[i]]; rows.push([data.XXX]); }


  dataRange = sheet.getRange(7, 2, rows.length, 1); 
  dataRange.setValues(rows);
    }
```

Comment: How about you post your code?

Answer (score 4):

Google Apps script and old versions of JS in general use functional scoping so any value declared within a function is not accessible by its containing environment unless it is returned.

Your function has no return statement so it returns undefined implicitly. As side effects it declares the two variables and then garbage collects them when the function is done.

You want to add a line to your `getDates()` function `return year;` and assign that to a variable within `one()`

The only way to access variables within a function after the function has terminated is to have that function (`getDates()`) return a function. That function will then contain the environment of the containing function and can access its variables even after that function has terminated. This is called a [closure](http://jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/closures.html) but is not very useful in your case.